# Why is $1$ a proper divisor?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, terminology, intuition

Intuitively, the proper divisors of an integer $n$ don't include $n$ because trivially, any number divides itself; but $1$ divides any integer as well.

What is the rationale for including $1$?

Comment: Proper divisor of a number $n$ means a divisor $d$ smaller than the original number $n$. This definition is diferent from being a trivial divisor. Every number $n$ has two trivial divisors: $n$ itself and $1$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The word "proper" commonly connotes "but different than" - for example, if A is a proper subset of B then A is a subset of B but different than B.

So 1 is a divisor of 6 but different than 6, making 1 a proper divisor of 6.

Comment: Is the empty set then considered a proper subset of any non-empty set?

Comment: If the adjective 'proper' in mathematics has the meaning you are saying it does, then everything makes sense.

Comment: Yes, the empty set is a proper subset of any non-empty set.  It is often referred to as the trivial subset.

Answer (score 0):

One decent reason for this definition is that when studying perfect numbers (which is an interesting field of study) it makes it easy to say that a perfect number is equal to the sum of its proper divisors.

Similarly, you can say that we count $1$ as relatively prime to all integers so that the totient function (number of integers less than $n$ which are relatively prime to $n$) will be multiplicative.  That is, if $m$ and $n$ are relatively prime, then
$$
\varphi(mn) = \varphi(m) \varphi(n)
$$